# How to embed one lightning web component in another web component

Tags: lightning-web-components, component, embedded, webhooks, parent-to-child

I have a component where i need to embed it to another component i am getting the below  error

No MODULE named markup://c:lifeCycleChild found : [markup://c:lifeCycleParent]

Below is My code :

1st Component : LifeCycleParent

```
<template>    
    <lightning-card  title="LifeCycleHooks parent component">
        <div class= "slds-var-m-around_medium">
            <input type="text" onkeyup={changeHandler}/>
            {name}
            <c-life-cycle-child></c-life-cycle-child>
        </div>    
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Js file :

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class LifeCycleParent extends LightningElement {

    constructor() {
        super()
        console.log("parent constructor called")

    }
    connectedCallback() {
        console.log("parent connectedCallback called")
    }
    renderedCallback() {
        console.log("parent renderedCallback called")
    }

    name

    changeHandler(event) {
        this.name = event.target.value
    }
}
```

XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>51.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
      <targets>
     <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
      <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
      <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

2nd component: lifeCycleChild
HtML file :

```
<template>
    <lightning-card  title="LifeCycleHook child component">
        <div class= "slds-var-m-around_medium">
         </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Js file :

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class LifeCycleChild extends LightningElement {
    constructor() {
        super()
        console.log("child constructor called")

    }
    connectedCallback() {
        console.log("child connectedCallback called")
    }
    renderedCallback() {
        console.log("child renderedCallback called")
    }
}
```

Could you please help me understand why i am getting the above error

Comment: There must be some issue in referencing the child component in the html file. Please share html file code as well.

Comment: Hi @AnkurGupta,                                                                                                                                                                                                                         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>51.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
      <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
      <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
      <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
</LightningComponentBundle>

Comment: When are you getting this error? I assume you are trying to deploy lifeCycleParent component in to the org via right click and deploy in org option in VS Code. If Yes, then you have to first deploy lifeCycleChild component  and then parent component as parent is having dependency on child component. or you can deploy it via package.xml file and include both component name together in that file to deploy.

Comment: Yes it worked fine thanks

Answer (score 1):

This error is coming because your are trying to deploy a component in the org for which dependecy is not available yet in the org. LifeCycleParent includes LifeCycleChild component and is dependent on the child component. You can deploy in 2 ways:

1. Include both component file name in mainfest -> package.xml file

```
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>lifeCycleParent</members>
        <members>lifeCycleChild</members>
        <name>LightningComponentBundle</name>
    </types>
    <version>49.0</version>
</Package>
```

2. If you are deploying components one at time using VS code right click and deploy this source to org  option, then first you have to deploy lifeCycleChild component and then lifeCycleParent component.